# implicit ob_start in require_once

Tags: php, output-buffering

Somewhere in my PHP script, a call to `ob_start()` is issued, and I am trying to find where exactly. To do this, I use xdebug, and proceed by dichotomy, calling `ob_get_contents()` which returns FALSE as long as `ob_start()` hasn't been called.

I have narrowed my code to:

```
<?php 
...
if ( ob_get_contents() ) { xdebug_break(); }
require_once( 'lib/local.php' );
if ( ob_get_contents() ) { xdebug_break(); }
...
?>
```

`lib/local.php` is a local, writeable file that contains nothing else than defines.

Now the funny part is this: if I replace `require_once( 'lib/local.php' )` with the contents of `lib/local.php`, the second `ob_get_contents()` returns  FALSE, as expected.

Now I am really puzzled at what's going on here. Insight, anyone?

Comment: Could you show the content of local.php?

Comment: @Jite actually I just found the solution: a utf8 BOM was present just before the `<?php`. Not sure if I should close the question or post an answer